# Jquery first table, last row selection

Tags: jquery

I'm having issues with the `tr:last`  selector.

I have a basic table:

```
<table id="myTable">
 <tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

When the user clicks on a link, It adds an addtional row to my table using:

```
$("a#more").live("click", function(){

  $table = $('#myTable');
  var a = $table.find('tr:last').clone(true);
  $table.find('tr:last').after(a);  

});
```

Which works like a charm. However, the issue starts when I decided to add an additional table in the last `td` of my table:

```
<table id="myTable">
 <tr>
  <td> 1 </td>
  <td>
    <table id="myTable2">
    <tr><td> Additional Information </td></tr>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

WHen I use `clone`  this time, it picks the last row of my second table and copies a new row to my second table. My goal is to duplicate ONLY the entire last row of my first table and creating a new `tr` with all of the contents in it (including a copy of the second table).

I'm not sure how to go about this.

Comment: `live` is deprecated and removed from 1.9. Use `on`

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I had no idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of

```
var a = $table.find('tr:last').clone(true);
```

Use [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) to restrict it to the original table:

```
var a = $table.children('tbody').children('tr:last').clone(true);
```

Comment: I'm wondering: is it guaranteed that `tbody` will be inserted by the browser?

Comment: @JanDvorak I always add it to the HTML, just to be sure.